# Building a regex for weird word combination

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hello I want to create a regex to find words which have capital words in between them. Can anyone please tell me how to find it?

For example: `I went to a school forEducation and then didn't study.`

I want words like `forEducation`. I think we use `[a-z][A-Z]` to find all alphabets but can't really find it. I am thinking along the lines of merging the above two options, but then how is it going to check for capital alphabets? Also I wouldn't want to select any words which have capital letters in the start, because they are valid.

Reason : This is occurring because of scraping text from online websites and they have no proper formatting. I get these words as text and want to replace them.

Comment: What do you mean you wouldn't want to select any words which have capital letters in the middle?

Comment: sorry about that - edited. i meant in start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm guessing correctly, you want to split words that are camelCased, right?

Then use

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, 
    "(?<=\p{Ll})  # Assert that the previous character is a lowercase letter" & chr(10) & _
    "(?=\p{Lu})   # Assert that the next character is an uppercase letter", 
    " ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
```

This changes

```
I went to a school forEducation and then didn't study.
```

into

```
I went to a school for Education and then didn't study.
```

Comment: oh my god. this is brilliant. a very big christmas hug for you and god bless your family with all joy and success. :) thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-zA-Z][a-z]*[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*
```

Start with any letter, followed by 0 or more lowercase letters, followed by a capital letter, followed by 0 or more letters (capitalized or not)